# Supporting multiple Relying Party origins / domains

Tags: passkey

How to go about supporting **multiple origins** if my service is hosted in multiple domains?

Example: I've a service called **MyJuiceShop** and it's available in `myjuiceshop.com` and also in `myjuiceshop.jp`. Users can login at both the domains.
Current implementation with `username/password` works as it queries the same database.

For Passkeys implementation, how should I go about it as relying party?
My concern here is that Passkey is tied to the origin/domain in User's device. If a user is visiting `myjuiceshop.jp` and has registered a Passkey with this domain, they'll not be prompted with a Passkey suggestion when they try to login while visiting `myjuiceshop.com`.

Is it possible to register at one domain (`*.com`) and available at other domains where my service is hosted (`*.jp`, `*.au`, etc) ?

I'm thinking to redirect users to a single domain (say *.com) from all other domains during registration phase. But, this will not solve the problem during login phase from other domains.

Comment: Can you redirect the login to a common URL the same as you could do for registration? Why do you have two different URLs which should use the same passkey login? You might want to look at something called "identity provider".

Answer (score 0):

As you've mentioned, as of now, there is no such flexibility in the WebAuthn specs.

There are couple of options here.

1. You can also redirect your users to the single domain which is same domain for the registration.
2. You can embed your registration page which is a single domain into your every login page.

The WebAuthn WG has been considered to have more flexible way to support multiple domains. So, if you can wait for the such work, you'd better to leverage the new way.